# Store switch error in admin magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

I have a custom module.
when I switch store view it not show anything.
[image]

normally it still working fine in all store view

[image]

**update:**
I have added it in XML file

```
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher">
            <action method="setUseConfirm">
                <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please share system.xml from the custom module

Comment: @YasirLatif Thank for your reply, Please check my update.

Comment: etc/adminhtml  etc/adminhtml/system.xml from your module?